# UnsupportedMediaException: Unsupported Content-Type: text/html Supported ones are: [text/xml]

Tags: java, xml

I tried to call web service from my java project(client). Then I got a exception

```
UnsupportedMediaException: Unsupported Content-Type: text/html Supported ones are:  [text/xml]
```

After studying so many answers in net, I came to know that my web service expects text/xml, but my client is not able to send that. How could I check what request my client is sending and how to convert that thing into text/xml so that my web service understands.

Comment: How are you composing the request in client side?

Answer (score 0):

You need to fix your java application to use text/xml as http header.
Java supports the mechanism so you can edit http header.
And to know what http request your client is sending, you can use wireshark or httpdebugger like fiddler.